# How do I access a route in Laravel, if Im using https?

Tags: laravel, https

Im not sure if my question is valid, I have a laravel app, by default I can access it using http protocol,

but due to security reasons, I was instructed to use https instead,
So I was planning to configure my apache and use the default-ssl.conf,

but before I do that, I want to know if changing it to https  will it affect my routes?

Comment: no, it will not affect your routes

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not affect your routes.

To make all helpers like `route()`, `url()`, `action()` etc generate HTTPS links change `http` to `https` in the `.env` file:

```
APP_URL=https://some.app
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the feedback im gonna try it and update you here after,
my problem would be updating my ajax urls one by one?

Answer (score 0):

It MAY affect your routes !

If you are using cloudflare for your ssl certificate, Laravel will not recognise it as a secure url, You will have to specify in your code that you want a secure url

for example for your assets, you may have to use

`secure_asset('img/photo.jpg')`

Comment: thank you, im not using cloudflare, im using and modifying the servers default-ssl config, so would it mean it will work?  but I would have to rewrite links like http, to https? is that what you meant,

Comment: You don't need to use this helper in this situation because `asset()` helper takes `APP_URL` from the `.env` file. Also, `secure_asset()` is not related to routes in any way.

Answer (score 0):

> Normal SSH and Cpanel

If you are using normal ssh provided by server providers then do not worry,
You just need to change in your **environment** file.

which is placed in **project_root/.env**  where you can change your **APP_URL** from **http://** to **https://**

Also you can directly change in **config/app.php**  in **'url'** parameter.

> cloudflare

[Answer of Mathieu Ferre is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48059432/2870548)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use mixed routes in your application you can use some laravel built-in helper methods.

use `secure_asset()` and `url('url',params, true)` the last param in `url()` is for securing route.

EDIT 1

there is also another function `secure_url` for securing url. If your application is using mixed routes.

Hope this helps.

Thanks